# External App OAuth failure connecting to salesforce

Tags: security, oauth2

I have an external app trying to connect to our salesforce using user credentials to create leads and contacts but Salesforce is rejection the connections. When I check the login history on user record in salesforce it says Status Restricted IP. But i have added those IP's to our NetworkAccess Trusted IP Ranges but still it is not working. Any help is appreciated.

If the user is sys admin it is working but with other user profiles it is not working even though profiles has enough permission for it work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused when a Connected App is created but the API user is not authorized to access. Follow these steps to resolve this:

Navigate to the Connected App Detail (Setup | Manage Apps | Connected Apps) for the appropriate Connected App, and under the OAuth policies section, Permitted Users is (most likely) set to "Admin approved users are pre-authorized".

1. To allow access to this app for a particular group of users:

   - Leverage "Manage Profiles" and the Profiles related list to authorize access to the appropriate Salesforce profiles (and associated users).
   - Alternatively, Leverage Permission Sets and the Permission Sets related list to authorize access at a more granular level.
2. To allow access to this App for all users:

   - Under the OAuth policies section, set Permitted Users to "All users may self-authorize".